# How do you get multiple fields from a database row?

Tags: php, sql, database, youtube

Thanks for reading, I was wondering if anyone knew if there is any way to retrieve multiple fields from a row in a database table automatically. What I mean is something similar to retrieving multiple fields from columns with code like this

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM table1 
    WHERE column1 LIKE 'info' 
    ORDER BY date_added DESC 
    LIMIT 4
```

My plan is to have four fields in a row, which will not always contain data, and have php code populate tabs.Some pages may only have one tab while others might have four. The problem is each column will probably need a different name. I don't know if this can be done and don't know if I explained it very well. Any input would be appreciated, thank you.

Sorry for not making it clear. I use that line of code for retrieving rows that have 'info' in the 'column1' column limited to four results. I should probably not have added that line of code into this question. What I am trying to do is have an automated system that will retrieve multiple fields from a single row and populate tabs. At present most rows have part of a youtube video code which, using php, gets inserted into the rest of the code on the webpage. What my goal is is to have multiple youtube videos contained in separate tabs fed in from a database. Some rows might only contain one video while others may contain four.

The problem is that I need to have four columns, one for each video, and I think the columns will need different names. My thinking is if there is data in one of the columns then, due to the code, it will contain the word 'youtube' so if I search that column of that row to see if it contains the word 'youtube' and if it does then add it to the webpage. My problem is I am not sure how to repeat that for the other tabs using other columns. If I each separately in each tab then the pages with only one or two youtube videos will have the extra code remaining in the other tabs.

Sorry this probably doesn't make much sense either. Its like the thinking of a madman. As you can probably tell I am not the most experienced man in the world but thanks for reading.

Comment: The kind of query that you show here will retrieve all of the fields from a database by row.

Comment: Is it possible that you mixed up cols and rows?

Comment: You could edit your question and show an example of the kind of output you are looking for. As it stands, it is a bit hard to understand

Comment: Your `WHERE` clause is not a proper `LIKE`. It should be `WHERE column1 LIKE '%info%'` to return all rows that contain info in column1.

Comment: Use http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Answer (score 0):

After some time and research I have come up with an answer to my question. Just to clarify what I was trying to do, I wanted to have 1 to 4 youtube clips on my page with thumbnails below. Only one clip would be displayed at a time.

I created 4 new columns in the database, video1, video2, video3, video4, and in these I put the youtube video code or set them to NULL. Now I created tabs that would only be displayed if the video field was not NULL.

```
 <?php
    if ($video1 != NULL) { ?>//skips if there are no youtube videos in database
 <div id="tabs" class="ui-tabs">
    <ul class="ui-tabs-nav">
         <li class="youtbe-li"><a href="#tabs-1">
         <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/<?=$subject['video1']?>/0.jpg"></a></li>
         //uses a thumbnail from youtube

        <?php
            if ($video2 != NULL) { ?>
               <li class="youtbe-li"><a href="#tabs-1">
               <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/<?=$subject['video2']?>/0.jpg"></a>
               </li>
        <?php }?>//repeat for the rest
    </ul>

   <div id="tabs-1">            
       <div class="youtube-clip">
           <iframe width="730" height="436"
           src="//www.youtube.com/embed/<?=$subject['video1']?>"></iframe>
       </div>                
   </div>//repeat for the rest

</div>
```